# How to prevent alamofire to put "&" sign to front of parameter

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm a beginner in Swift. I'm trying to create an application using PUBG api. I add my headers using Alamofire. I have a text field on my storyboard , I enter my nickname there and get the data from pubg api. My problem is Alamofire adds "&" sign to front of parameters so this crashes the url. How can I prevent Alamofire to put "&" sign to parameter?

```
let playerURL = "https://api.pubg.com/shards/pc-eu/players?filter[playerNames]"

func findPlayer(playerName:String){

    let httpParameters : Parameters = ["":playerName]

    Alamofire.request(playerURL,method:.get,parameters:httpParameters,encoding:URLEncoding.default,headers:httpHeaders).responseJSON{response in switch response.result{

    case .success(let value):
        let response = JSON(value)
        print(response["data"])

    case .failure(_):
        return
        }
    }
}
```

URL should be like this:

> https://api.pubg.com/shards/pc-eu/players?filter%5BplayerNames%5D=PlayerName

Instead it becomes this:

> https://api.pubg.com/shards/pc-eu/players?filter%5BplayerNames%5D&=PlayerName

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Alamofire to encode the parameters, then you need to let it encode the parameters:

```
let playerURL = "https://api.pubg.com/shards/pc-eu/players"

....

let httpParameters : Parameters = ["filter[playerNames]": playerName]
...
```

---

My entire test case is as follows:

- Create a blank one-view project
- In AppDelegate add:

  ```
  let playerURL = "https://api.pubg.com/shards/pc-eu/players"

  func findPlayer(playerName:String){

      let httpParameters : Parameters = ["filter[playerNames]": playerName]

      let request = Alamofire.request(playerURL,
                                  method:.get,
                                  parameters:httpParameters)
      print(request)
  }
  ```
- In `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` add:

  ```
  findPlayer(playerName: "PLAYERNAME")
  ```
- Run

Output:

```
GET https://api.pubg.com/shards/pc-eu/players?filter%5BplayerNames%5D=PLAYERNAME
```

Comment: Tried this.It still puts & before them.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this; please post the code you're using to demonstrate that. My code produces: `https://api.pubg.com/shards/pc-eu/players?filter%5BplayerNames%5D=PLAYERNAME`

Comment: Okay somehow the link i'm getting works now i dont know why.Also thanks for the reply.